# HighCharts, how to change the coloring on the headline on the y-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If you take a peak at the bar charts on this lovely little web page http://simnet.is/ivar84/ , on all the charts all the coloring is orange, but the y-axis headline is grey
on a basic bar chart from High Charts. How can I access the coloring on the y-axis headline? I want, for example, *Strikes* to match the orange coloring of the rest of the chart. I am unable to find it within the JavaScript library from High charts. How can I access and change the coloring?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the color for the title and subtitle like you would set any other color in Highcharts :

```
title: {
      style: {
         color: '#FFCC00',
         font: '16px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
      }
   },
   subtitle: {
      style: {
         color: '#FFCC00',
         font: '12px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
      }
   },
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TX5jV/)